# Rails Query based on hasManyBelongsToMany relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following models

```
venues(id, name, ....)
categories(id, name, ....)
categories_venues(id, venue_id, category_id)
```

I want to query venues based which have the relation of `Categories ID = (1)/(2) or (1 and 2)`

How can i do a where query for the relation of a HABTM?

**EDIT**

Using the following query it solved the problem.

venues = Venue.joins(:categories_venues).where(:categories_venues => {:category_id => values})

***I want to exclude repetitive records from the query and a particular ID from the results?***

```
---
- !ruby/object:Venue
  attributes:
    id: 2
    name: Ooty
    slug: ooty
    created_at: 2014-06-21 22:10:52.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-07-05 17:33:26.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Venue
  attributes:
    id: 4
    name: Munnar
    slug: munnar
    created_at: 2014-08-25 03:42:13.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-08-25 03:42:13.000000000 Z
- !ruby/object:Venue
  attributes:
    id: 2
    name: Ooty
    slug: ooty
    created_at: 2014-06-21 22:10:52.000000000 Z
    updated_at: 2014-07-05 17:33:26.000000000 Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query to get venue details based on category

```
venues = Venue.joins(:categories_venues).where(:categories_venues => {:category_id => values})
```

Comment: can i pass the values as an array?

Comment: Yes you can pass array as well venues = Venue.joins(:categories_venues).where(:categories_venues => {:category_id => [1,2]})

Comment: is there a way to exclude one of the IDs from the query result. since i am trying to find similar results based on category

Comment: is there a way to removed repetive records like the Distinct result set. have edited the question

Comment: You can do by using uniq method  Venue.joins(:categories_venues).where(:categories_venues => {:category_id => [1,2]}).uniq

Comment: Uniq is method in Array class which returns distinct element from your ActiveRecord result array

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if understanding you right. Plz provide sql code if you think this answer does not provide the right query
But i think, it should be just

```
 Venue.joins(:categories).where(category_id: [1,2])
```

Comment: there is a join table in between which is a HABTM

Comment: yeah, the over solution ist better actually as it save an extra join